# lightning:radioGroup required= true not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components

How can I display required field error if no option is selected? Making 'required="true"' is not working on button click.

```
<lightning:radioGroup 
        aura:id="mygroup"
        name="radioButtonGroup"
        label=" My Label "
        options="{! v.options }"
        required="true"
        value="{! v.radioGrpValue }"
        onchange="{! c.handleChange }"
        />
```

Comment: When do you want to display the error to the user?

Comment: Actually, I want to call this component in the Screen Flow, so when 'NEXT' button is clicked without selecting any option from the radioGroup.

Comment: So to trigger the field validation you have to execute a method on this field `input.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();` this will highlight any error for the field.

Comment: This is my controller code so far    btnPressed: function(cmp, event, helper) {
          
 var selectedRadioOption = cmp.find("mygroup");
 if ($A.util.isEmpty(selectedRadioOption.get("v.value"))){
  // show error somehow
 }
 else{
  var actionClicked = event.getSource().getLocalId();
  var navigate = cmp.get('v.navigateFlow');
  navigate(actionClicked);
 }
     
   }

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 Thank you so much, it worked!

Comment: Posted the same thing with JS part, you can use this to validate multiple fields at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To trigger the lightning validation on the fields you can follow this approach:

**Component**

```
<lightning:radioGroup 
    aura:id="validate"
    name="radioButtonGroup"
    label=" My Label "
    options="{! v.options }"
    required="true"
    value="{! v.radioGrpValue }"
    onchange="{! c.handleChange }"
    />
```

**Controller**

```
btnPressed: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    if (helper.isValid(cmp)){
        var actionClicked = event.getSource().getLocalId();
        var navigate = cmp.get('v.navigateFlow');
        navigate(actionClicked);
    }
}
```

**Helper**

```
isValid: function (c, id) {
    var validateFields = c.find(id || 'validate');
    var isValid;
    if (validateFields) {
        isValid = [].concat(validateFields).reduce(function (validSoFar, input) {
            input.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
            return validSoFar && input.get('v.validity').valid;
        }, true);
    }
    return isValid;
}
```